# Linkifying tweets using simplepie

Tags: php, twitter, hyperlink, simplepie, linkify

I am trying to make the links contained in certain tweets work on my twitter widget, for instance when I tweet an image and twitter turns it into a short link. Here is the code... Thank you in advance for your help!

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_echo_twitter' ) ) {
    function wp_echo_twitter($username) {
        include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-simplepie.php' );

        // Fetch feed, set cache locaiton, and initialize function
        $feed = new SimplePie();
        $feed->set_feed_url("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$username.atom?count=200");
        $feed->set_cache_location( ABSPATH . WPINC );
        $feed->init();
        $feed->handle_content_type();

        // Output tweet
        foreach ($feed->get_items(0, 1) as $item):
            echo '<p class="hero-p" style="margin-bottom: 9px;">"' . $item->get_description() . '"</p>' . '<span><a href="' . $item->get_permalink() . '">' . $item->get_date('D, M j, Y') . '</a></span>';
        endforeach;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('simplepie.inc');
$cache = "/cache";
$duration = 3600;

// turn urls, hashtags and @replies into links
function twitterify($ret) {
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a target=\"_new\" href=\"\\2\" >\\2</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a target=\"_new\" href=\"http://\\2\" >\\2</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a target=\"_new\" href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" >@\\1</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a target=\"_new\" href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" >#\\1</a>", $ret);
return $ret;
}

//  make the time twittery
function niceTime($time) {
$delta = time() - $time;
if ($delta < 60) {
return 'less than a minute ago.';
} else if ($delta < 120) {
return 'about a minute ago.';
} else if ($delta < (45 * 60)) {
return floor($delta / 60) . ' minutes ago.';
} else if ($delta < (90 * 60)) {
return 'about an hour ago.';
} else if ($delta < (24 * 60 * 60)) {
return 'about ' . floor($delta / 3600) . ' hours ago.';
} else if ($delta < (48 * 60 * 60)) {
return '1 day ago.';
} else {
return floor($delta / 86400) . ' days ago.';
}
}

function getLastTweet($username){
$twitter = new SimplePie("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$username.rss", $cache, $duration);
foreach ($twitter->get_items(0,1) as $item) :
$pubDate = $item->get_item_tags('','pubDate');
$data = $pubDate[0]['data'];
$time = niceTime(strtotime(str_replace("+0000", "", $data)));

echo "<p>"; 
echo twitterify(str_replace("$username: ", "", $item->get_title()));
echo "<span>$time</span>"; 
echo "</p>";
endforeach;
}
// show tweet
getLastTweet("twitterusername");
```